# Expo - How to make custom permission message

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to change the camera message when I try to reach user's camera.

It returns default "Allow xx to use your camera" message and I want to change It with my own permission message.

Where to change It and how?

Here's my camera code below.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted')
    })()
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Expo documentation:

> To request permissions on iOS, you have to describe why the permissions are requested and install the library that can request this permission. In the managed workflow, you can do that by customizing the ios.infoPlist property in your app.json file. When using the bare workflow, you have to edit the info.plist file directly.

So, in app.json:

```
"infoPlist": {
  "NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to scan barcodes on event tickets."
}
```

In a non-managed workflow, you can edit `NSCameraUsageDescription` in your Info.plist for the app in Xcode.

Comment: The infoPlist property needs to be added inside ios section (as it has no effect on Android).